# Parse Excel to BizTalk and save it in database

Tags: biztalk

How to use BizTalk To disassemble Excel File .. Then Save these data in Database?

Can anyone provide me detailed steps of how to achieve this or any existing link for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow - this is pretty open ended! 
The steps you would generally take are:

1) Generate a Flat File schema that represents your excel file structure. As it's excel I'm assuming that your file is actually a CSV?

2) Create a custom pipeline that implements a flat file disassembler to convert CSV to Xml.

3) Using the WCF-LOB adapter, generate schemas for the Table you want to insert to. You might want to front this with a stored proc. I'm assuming an SQL or ORACLE database as you don't say what DB you are using!

4) Map your input Xml file to your Table/SP Schema.

5) Send your insert request to your DB (advise using Composite operations or a User defined table parameter to to avoid looping through your Xml and sending line-by-line!)

This is pretty high-level but frankly you are asking quite a few questions in one go!

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In case it isn't not a CSV flat file  as assumed by teepeeboy, and it is actually a XLS file you want to parse you will need something like [FarPoint Spread for BizTalk](http://www.fpoint.com/biztalk/default.aspx).  We've successfully used this to parse incoming XLS files attached to e-mails.  The other option would be to write your own Pipeline component to do it but would be a lot of work.  Other than that the steps that teepeeboy outline are what I would do as well.